# How to make for loop not iterate entire array but only specified index

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am new to programming and am currently learning C++, here is my code

```
           switch (userEditChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Item to remove (1-5): ";
                std::cin >> removedItem;
                std::cout << " Item to add: ";
                std::cin >> itemAdded;

                for (int i = removedItem; i < amazonSize; i++)
                {
                    amazon[i] = itemAdded;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

my program works but instead of changing only the first value in the array, it changes the first and the rest. How do I make it only change the first and keep the rest the same? Thanks in advance!

I tried messing around with the i++ but when I took it out or messed with it, once I reached it, my program ended.

Comment: Whats the loop for?

Comment: Yeah, just get rid of the loop and access the array with `amazon[removedItem] = itemAdd;` You might want to check if the user input is in the range of allowed values.

Comment: *my program works but...* -- So your program isn't working.

Comment: You should provide a [mre], in given code we e.g. cannot see what `amazon` actually is (presumably a classic/raw array – and you might want to prefer a `std::vector` or `std::array` over; the former for variable, the latter for fixed size; both provide their  – current – size so you don't need to store separately).

Comment: Are you sure that "changing only the first value in the array" is really what you are trying to do? Most of your code seems to imply that what you are supposed to do is remove an item from the array, which does indeed require a loop. Please [edit] to clarify that and if necessary change your MRE ([mre]) to not mention removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuume your array is a STL container, such as `vector`/`list`.
if you want to change the item removedItem(index) to itemAdded, you can use

```
amazon[i] = itemAdded;
```

instead of

```
for (int i = removedItem; i < amazonSize; i++)
{
  amazon[i] = itemAdded;
}
```

for the meaning of the `for` loop, it's checking all of the items from the removedItem(index), but you just want to modify one.

Comment: This misses a definition of `i`. Also you probably want to rephrase the "removedItem(index)", at least I don't see what you mean by that, possibly "the item at the index stored in `removedItem` ". I suspect however that the identifier "removedItem" indicates that this code was inappropriatly adapted from a function to delete an item, which in an array is a noticably more difficult task than overwriting an existing one. This would need clarification from OP before answering, because the rest of the code implies that it IS in fact their goal - which is why the question is closed.